# Predis using PHP: How to get which Redis node ( host ) that holds a particular key?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis, predis, redis-cluster

I'm using Redis cluster using Predis in PHP, I'm doing simple

```
$image_urls = $client->get($key)
```

Now I want to get the host address where Redis found the key-value pair because it also contains local images, I need to get the full link of those images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getConnectionByKey()` to get that information.

In example:

```
$cluster = new PredisCluster();
$cluster->add($connection);
$cluster->add($connection2);
$connection = $cluster->getConnectionByKey($key);
```

source: [PredisClusterTest.php](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/6ab10b2b705ea5121f2c1ea87a290f6871c32ebd/tests/Predis/Connection/Aggregate/PredisClusterTest.php)